# Dotnet Graphql Response Deserialization

Tags: c#, json, serialization, graphql, json-deserialization

I am making a dotnet web appplication that consumes a GraphQL API. The problem I have is that after I execute the query the response doesn't match with my entity model, I supose that it is because the response has a edge and node tags.

can some body help me?

Follow my code:

Model:

```cs
public class ProductResponseType 
    {
        
        public ListGraphType<Product> products { get; set; }
    }


    public class Product : ObjectGraphType
    {
        public List<ProductNode> edgeProduct { get; set; }

        public class ProductNode
        {
            public string title { get; set; }
            public ListGraphType<Variant> variants { get; set; }

        }

    }

    public class Variant : ObjectGraphType
    {
        public List<VariantNode> variantProduct { get; set; }
        public class VariantNode
        {

            public string Id { get; set; }


            public string Title { get; set; }


            public string Price { get; set; }


            public string Sku { get; set; }

        }

    }
```

Query excecution:

```cs
try
            {
                GraphQLHttpClientOptions graphQLOptions = new GraphQLHttpClientOptions
                {
                    EndPoint = new Uri(_GraphQlURI),

                };

                var graphQLClient = new GraphQLHttpClient(graphQLOptions, new GraphQL.Client.Serializer.Newtonsoft.NewtonsoftJsonSerializer());
                graphQLClient.HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Access-Token", "token");
                graphQLClient.HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
                    
             
                var productRequest = new GraphQLRequest
                {
                    Query = @"query {
                              products(first:2) {
                                edges {
                                  node {
                                      title
                                    variants(first: 2) {
                                      edges {
                                        node {
                                          id
                                          title
                                          price
                                          sku
                                        }
                                      }
                                    }
                                  }
                                }
                              }
                            }"
                };

               
                var productResponse =  await graphQLClient.SendQueryAsync<ProductResponseType>(productRequest);



                return "";
                //return graphQLResponse.Data.WebUrl;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogWarning(ex, "Error al introducir crear el checkout");
                return null;
            }
```

the response i get when i use the postman:

```
 "data": {
        "products": {
            "edges": [
                {
                    "node": {
                        "title": "the tittle",
                        "variants": {
                            "edges": [
                                {
                                    "node": {
                                        "id": "The ID",
                                        "title": "The variant tittle",
                                        "price": "0.00",
                                        "sku": "the sku code"
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should either adapt your model to what the JSON deserialization returns or map those types to your model. The former could be done easily, using the Visual Studio "Paste JSON as classes" feature and the latter could be done using AutoMapper. Bothe alternatives should work, decide witch one you want to go and if you encounter a problem edit your question with the specific problem, error and behavior

Comment: i tried it but still not working...

Comment: Any example would be appreciated

Answer (score 4):

Paste the GraphQL response into https://app.quicktype.io/?l=csharp and it will generate all the classes you need

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at the JSON response as interpreted by `GraphQL.Client`? What I noticed is that, while my JSON looks perfect in Postman, the first node (`products` in your case) comes back like this:

```
"products", [{
```

instead of like this:

```
"products": {
```

So now I'm trying to rewrite my code without using `GraphQL.client`.